# Dapper use ZonedDateTime mapping of NodaTime Npgsql Plugin

Tags: dapper, npgsql, nodatime

I'm trying out the new Nodatime plugin for npgsql and have an issue mapping the result to a ZonedDateTime.

With raw npgsql I can retrieve a timestamptz value and have it mapped to Instant or ZonedDateTime.

```
NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.UseNodatime();
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection("connection_string"))
{
    connection.Open();

    var command = new NpgsqlCommand("set time zone 'Europe/Vienna'; select now();", connection);

    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(0));  // by default the npgsql Nodatime plugin maps timestamptz to Instant
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetFieldValue<ZonedDateTime>(0)); // mapping to ZonedDateTime
    }

}
```

Now I'm trying to get the ZonedDateTime mapping to work with Dapper:

```
public class DapperTest 
{
    public ZonedDateTime DapperTime { get; set;}
}
NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.UseNodatime();
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection("connection_string"))
{

    connection.Open();

    var d = connection.Query<DapperTest>("set time zone 'Europe/Vienna'; select now() as dappertime;").First();

    Console.WriteLine(d);

}
```

With this code I get an Exception:

> Error parsing column 0 (dappertime=2017-10-30T12:08:43Z - Object)

But when I change the "DapperTime" Property to Instant it is working fine.

Is there a way to force Dapper to use the ZonedDateTime mapping provided by the npgsql Nodatime plugin?

Answer (score 3):

Dapper supports the concept of "type handlers" to convert to/from types it doesn't recognize.  In this case, you'll need to register a class that implements `SqlMapper.TypeHandler<ZonedDateTime>`.

I've already done this for several other Noda Time types in my [`Dapper-NodaTime`](https://github.com/mj1856/Dapper-NodaTime) library.  Sorry that it doesn't yet support `ZonedDateTime`.  I'll look into adding it, with an eye to the npgsql usage you demonstrated.  (I'd also gladly accept a pull request.)

Comment: Thats great that you already started such a project. I tried implementing a ZonedDateTimeHandler like you did for the other types but didn't get far. You can look at it [here](https://gist.github.com/mibiio/1b4af21987695312d973d97c0b79701b) I didn't find a way to influcence the typemapping npgsql does from the SqlMapper it still returns an Instant. One other way I thought could work is to do Instant -> ZonedDateTime conversion in the SqlMapper but for this to work access to underlying NpgsqlConnection is necessary (connection.Timezone).

Comment: Yeah, I spent a few hours on it last night.  Needs lots of work before it's ready for postgres at all.  It's too SQL Server specific at the moment.  Will do more in this area.  Please leave the question open and unanswered here in case someone else has a good idea about this before I get it working. :)